# efficient sampling from beta-binomial distribution in python

Tags: python, random, distribution, stochastic, beta-distribution

for a stochastic simulation I need to draw a lot of random numbers which are beta binomial distributed.

At the moment I implemented it this way (using python):

```
import scipy as scp
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete

class beta_binomial(rv_discrete):
       """
       creating betabinomial distribution by defining its pmf
       """
       def _pmf(self, k, a, b, n):
          return scp.special.binom(n,k)*scp.special.beta(k+a,n-k+b)/scp.special.beta(a,b)
```

so sampling a random number x can be done by:

```
betabinomial = beta_binomial(name="betabinomial")
x = betabinomial.rvs(0.5,0.5,3) # with some parameter
```

The problem is, that sampling one random number takes ca. 0.5ms, which is in my case dominating the whole simulation speed. The limiting element is the evaluation of the beta functions (or gamma functions within these).

Does anyone has a great idea how to speed up the sampling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is working and lightly tested code which seems to be faster, using compound distribution property of [Beta-Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).

We sample `p` from beta and then using it as parameter for binomial. If you would sample large sized vectors, it would be even faster.

```
import numpy as np

def sample_Beta_Binomial(a, b, n, size=None):
    p = np.random.beta(a, b, size=size)
    r = np.random.binomial(n, p)

    return r

np.random.seed(777777)
q = sample_Beta_Binomial(0.5, 0.5, 3, size=10)
print(q)
```

Output is

```
[3 1 3 2 0 0 0 3 0 3]
```

Quick test

```
np.random.seed(777777)

n = 10
a = 2.
b = 2.
N = 100000

q = sample_Beta_Binomial(a, b, n, size=N)

h = np.zeros(n+1, dtype=np.float64) # histogram
for v in q: # fill it
    h[v] += 1.0

h /= np.float64(N) # normalization
print(h)
```

prints histogram

```
[0.03752 0.07096 0.09314 0.1114  0.12286 0.12569 0.12254 0.1127  0.09548 0.06967 0.03804]
```

which is quite similar to green graph in the Wiki page on Beta-Binomial

Comment: Thanks!
I expected a more technical response but this simple solution works perfect and is more than ten times faster. But of course it has not all the nice properties of the rv_discrete class. Which is just for sampling totally fine.

Comment: @Balou well, you could always replace class method with you own functions: `betabinomial.rvs = sample_Beta_Binomial` and have it both ways